# Flutter integration_test: How to automate multiple selection of widgets by long pressing shift key and mouse drag

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-integration-test

I am trying to automate, in flutter web integration_test, wherein I want to select multiple widgets by long pressing shift key and mouse drag. May I know if this is possible, if yes, then how? or if not possible, then is there any alternate way to achieve this selection?

For reference, I have attached an image to get more clarity if my objective.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hold the shift you can try like this

```
await simulateKeyDownEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.shiftLeft);
```

You can try creating a gesture then starting it based on location

```
final Offset firstLocation = tester.getCenter(find.byKey('keyName'));
final TestGesture gesture = await tester.startGesture(firstLocation, pointer: 5);
    await tester.pump();
```

Then to drag you can use

```
final Offset secondLocation = tester.getCenter(find.byKey('Key2Name'));
    await gesture.moveTo(secondLocation);
    await tester.pump();
```

Then do gesuture.up

```
 await gesture.up();
```

and to release shift you can do

```
await simulateKeyUpEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.shiftLeft);
```

Comment: First of all, apologies for delayed acknowledgement. Was busy with some other tasks in hand.
You are a savior! Your solution is amazing. Works for me.